# How to resolve flutter doctor issues with home brew?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using OS X High Sierra.
I started with the install documentation here:
https://flutter.io/setup-macos/
however I cannot seem to install libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller.

When I start flutter doctor I get the following:

```
✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install, run:
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
```

So I do as requested:

```
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
Error: libimobiledevice 1.2.0_2 is already installed
To install HEAD_2, first run `brew unlink libimobiledevice`


brew install ideviceinstaller
Warning: ideviceinstaller 1.1.0_4 is already installed
```

After that if I call the doctor again, the same error as above is displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sometimes the doctor displays old errors that have been already resolved. You can just try continuing with the instruction to see if everything runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

In MacOS After many hours I solved it by following all these steps:

1- Go to `https://brew.sh` website and copy& run "Install Homebrew" command in terminal as below:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then run all these commands in terminal:

2- `brew install wget`

3- uninstall ideviceinstaller : `brew uninstall ideviceinstaller -g`

4-uninstall libimobiledevice : `brew uninstall libimobiledevice -g`

5-install libimobiledevice with --HEAD : `brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice -g`

6-install ideviceinstaller : `brew install ideviceinstaller -g`

7- `sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown/*`

8- Then run `./flutter doctor` and it's solved for me :)

Comment: -g is invalid parameter for brew uninstall command. Did you mean -f as by force?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to install flutter with brew

tap fabsb/flutter repository

```
brew tap fabsb/flutter
```

Then install flutter:

```
brew cask install flutter
```

Finally validate your installation:

```
flutter doctor
```

To remove flutter and this tap:

```
brew cask uninstall flutter
brew untap fabsb/flutter
```

source:

https://github.com/fabsb/homebrew-flutter